# Why am I unable to use Sass-rem for CSS variables?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I am trying to use the sass-rem library for converting pixels to rem values.
It is working fine when I am using it for different CSS properties but when I try to use it in CSS variables as show below then it does not work properly.

```
--width: rem(640px);
width: rem(640px);
```

on compiling it should be as

```
--width: 40rem;
width: 40rem;
```

but I still see as

```
--width: rem(640px);
width: 40rem;
```

if you notice for variables value does not convert to rem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use interpolation for css variables

Do:

```
--width: {rem(640px)};
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it in this way

```
--width: #{rem(80px)};
```

It gives the output as

```
--width: 5rem
```